# Paste Special Not Working more than 1 time: VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets in my workbook, "Sheet1" and "Data". In Sheet1 I have used a `Worksheet_Change` macro so that when a change happens in column C:

1. A timestamp appears in column D
2. That range will get copied into the "Data" sheet.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Location As Range
    If Target.Column > 3 Or Target.Column < 3 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(Target.Row, 4) = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("data").Unprotect
    Sheets("data").Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("data").Protect
    Range("a1").Select
End Sub
```

My problem is that the `PasteSpecial` is not working more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is being copied as you have used Selection and that depends upon how you input value in column C, whether by hitting Enter or Ctrl+Enter.
Say if you input a value in B2 and press Enter to submit it, cell B3 will get selected and as per your code a range from row3 will be copied to Data sheet. Whereas if you hit Ctrl+Enter, the selection will remain in B2 so a range from row2 will be copied to data sheet.
But that you can tweak yourself.

See if the tweaked code works for you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Location As Range
If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Cells(Target.Row, 4) = Now
Application.EnableEvents = True
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Sheets("data").Unprotect
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("data").Protect
Range("a1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the `EnableEvents` flags around the paste unless you also have sheet change code in the "data" sheet...

Comment: Good catch Wolfie! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that unprotecting the sheet was clearing the clipboard, meaning there was nothing to paste! Here is adapted code, which I've also changed in a couple of other ways to greatly improve it, see the comments for details.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Location As Range
    ' Use <> to mean "not equal to"
    If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' Fully qualify the cells object
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Target.Row, 4).Value = Now
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ' Avoid using .Select and Selection, the user could have clicked anywhere after the value change
    ' Use a With block to fully qualify your range objects
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")
        .Unprotect
        ' Copy immediately before paste
        Target.EntireRow.Copy
        .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Protect
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Currently, this just overwrites the same line on the "data" sheet, because the data you're pasting has nothing in column A, so the `End(xlDown)` in column A returns the same position. You may need to change this to column C, or use

```
.Cells(Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
```

Which is still column dependant but goes up to get the last row. There is a dot `.` before `Cells` because that line would be within the `With` block.